# Problem binding data to NG bootstrap typeahead in Angular from web API

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using NG-Bootstrap's typeahead feature. My data is coming from a web api, in the following format, which was changed from a previous format. The old format was:

```
result: Array(749)
[0 … 99]
0: "0000105862"
1: "0000105869"
2: "0000105875"
3: "0000110855"
4: "0000110856"
5: "0000110859"
6: "0000111068"
7: "0000111069"
8: "0000111077"
9: "0000112050"
etc
```

The new format is:

```
{  
   "result":[  
      {  
         "graphical":{  
            "link":"https://link.com",
            "value":"82374982374987239487"
         },
         "id":{  
            "link":"https://links.com",
            "value":"39485039485039485093485093"
         },
         "serial_number":"2837492837498237498"
      },
   ]
}
```

I have a service which brings this data from in, which is as follows:

```
getSerials(customerId): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.serialApiUrl + "?customer_id=" + customerId)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

This is then injected into the component.ts as follows:

```
public si_id = [];

private getSerials() {
  this.service.getSerials(this.customer_id).subscribe((data) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < data['result'].length; i++) {
      this.si_id.push(data['result'][i]);
  }
    console.log('Data' + data);
    this.loading = false;
    console.log('Result - ', data);
    console.log('Serial data is received');
  })
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getSerials();
    this.serviceForm = new FormGroup({
    customer_id: new FormControl(this.customer_id),
    si_id: new FormControl(this.si_id[0], Validators.required),
});
}

public model: any;

search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(term => term === '' ? []
        : this.si_id.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10))
    )
```

**Then in the html:**

```
<ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
   <ngb-highlight [result]="r" [term]="t">here</ngb-highlight>
</ng-template>
<input id="si_id" type="text" placeholder="Serial number" formControlName="si_id" class="form-input"
[ngbTypeahead]="search" [resultTemplate]="rt" />
```

I get the following error when I try to use the TypeAhead and its not working. Any help would be great.

```
ERROR TypeError: v.toLowerCase is not a function
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: How to you filter your content? Is it based on serial number or any other property?

Comment: Serial Number is what I need to display

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are applying `toLowerCase()` method to an object.

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(term => term === '' ? []
        : this.si_id.filter(v => v.serial_number.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10))
```

Based on your structure:

```js
const data = {
  "result": [{
    "graphical": {
      "link": "https://link.com",
      "value": "82374982374987239487"
    },
    "id": {
      "link": "https://links.com",
      "value": "39485039485039485093485093"
    },
    "serial_number": "2837492837498237498"
  }, ]
}

const si_id = [];

// You are looping here.
for (var i = 0; i < data['result'].length; i++) {
  si_id.push(data['result'][i]);
}

// Filter it here
si_id.map(m => {
  console.log(m.serial_number)
});
```

Comment: That did not work, the problem is with the for loop in the code: `for (var i = 0; i < data['result'].length; i++) {
      this.si_id.push(data['result'][i]);
  }` as the structure of the json has changed I think this method would too.??

Comment: The response is like the new format of json as above

Comment: Getting closer now the typeahead has just [object object] as the selections

Comment: my structure is public si_id = []; how to do this according to your code above?

Comment: Still have object object in the typeahead, although the console has got the data

Comment: But I need to return the data which is on the api?

Comment: You need to return Serial number. Access the object property like: `.serial_number`

Comment: Where would I need to do that?